# Android, Location Coordinates changing when sitting still

Tags: android, gps, location, coordinates

I'm writing a GPS app to aid me in my day job. I'm rather new to android development (my background is php and a small amount of C#) and this is my first attempt at GPS. The first thing I want to do is build a small app that tracks when GPS signal drops and records the last known coordinate before dropping and the First GPS coordinate after it picks up. If I determine that GPS is stable I'm going to build a GPS system for navigating to the correct building and door during emergency calls, this will be in what is essentially a private city in a hazardous enviroment.

I figured the first step in the first app would be to simply get the coordinates. I have that set up using the fine Location permission. I noticed that the coordinates for both longitude and latitude change even when I am sitting still. It is not the entire number that is changing it is the last 3 to 5 numbers. Some times it is a big jump and sometimes it is a small jump. Sometimes the number increases and sometimes it decreases, the changing is non stop.

My question is should I be worrying about this with it being such a small part of the over all number (there are around 8 numbers after the decimal, sometimes less)? I need my final GPS application to work well every time, lives will depend on it, thanks in advance.

Comment: That depends if you want your application to be precise a 5m or 1km.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can worry about it if you want, but there's nothing you can do about it. GPS will always fluctuate slightly due to changes in the signals that the device is receiving. As a side note, it seems that you're trying to use GPS indoors - which is always going to be inaccurate almost to the point of being useless for your situation. It really depends on your environment though.

Comment: Oh, now I feel foolish. I took it outside and the numbers stopped jumping. I had taken it outside previously but I was looking at the numbers before the decimal trying to get them to change. I looked up how to read coordinates and realized that those numbers were not going to change just driving around the block. Sense it does not work indoors does that include inside of cars? EDIT: I went back outside to go get in the car and before I made it there I realized that the numbers were jumping again when I was standing in the same spot as last time

Answer (score 0):

So I did as user3109468 said and went out side. I wrote down the starting coordinate and paced out around 70 feet and wrote down the ending coordinates. I ran them through Here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html  which gave me the results in km. I ran it through google to convert to feet and it gave me 68.372703412 feet. I know from when I was thinking about a gps module for my Arduino board that GPS is only accurate within about 6 feet. my "app" is less than two foot off so it is within the allowable range. The numbers are fluctuating but are not a problem. thank you user3109468 for your help.